# how to ensure that a user does not accidentally read my CGI code

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cgi

How can I ensure that if a user accidentally typed `http://mysite/test.cgi` they don't get to read my code? I'm using Ubuntu as my web server. My CGI scripts are stored in `/cgi-bin` directory but when a user accesses the URL above, the code is exposed.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not able to upload images but there is a difference of rendering html between /localhost/test.cgi and /localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi. my worry is that if a user accidentally or knowingly ran the first one they will be able to view my code. The .cgi file is stored in /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory

Comment: to be honest with you @Sinan...this is new teritory. Where should i store the CGI scripts?

Comment: OK, but Apache configuration is not a programming question. See [CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html) in Apache docs.

Comment: Thanks @Sinan. I created a new directory /var/www/cgi-bin and configured 000-default to match the same. I'm happy to say that it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu is your server's OS but what is your web server software? On Ubuntu, it is most likely Apache HTTP Server: http://httpd.apache.org

Apache has configuration files where you can set the behaviour of your CGI files and cgi-bin directory per domain.

Look for a file named httpd.conf or apache.conf or apache2.conf.

You will find the configuration documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html

If you modify your configuration, you will have to restart the web server (not the machine, the HTTP server process AKA daemon) to apply your changes.

Comment: Sorry guys...i meant Ubuntu OS, Apache webserver